# Responsive images in a responsive grid

Tags: html, grid

I've created a responsive grid which works great, but I would like to insert images into them which shrink when the grid does. This is my grid.  What would I use to insert 1 image into each section below the heading? Thankyou

```
<div class="port">
          <div class="columns eight">
            <h1>Heading</h1>

            <p>Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. </p>
            </div>
          <div class="columns eight">
            <h1>Heading</h1>

            <p>Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. </p>
            </div>
          <div class="columns eight">
            <h1>Heading</h1>

            <p>Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. </p>
            </div>
          <div class="columns eight">
            <h1>Heading</h1>

            <p>Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. </p>
            </div>
            </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jr034bb/

Comment: well you should post a fiddle or your CSS so we can have a working example to test with, but setting the `img` tag to a percentage (ex: `width:100%`) should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have already added:

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

So that will adjust your images accordingly. Also an image has a defined height already so you don't need to add `height: auto`. Setting either a width or a height will auto adjust the other one when it resizes.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5jr034bb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

To create responsive images you need to give them a width or a height. If, for example, we want the images to scale in width, we set the width to 100% and the height to auto.

```css
.grid-half {
  margin: 5%;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
.grid-half img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-half">
  <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="grid-half">
  <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but im still confused to how id integrate that into my code. Iv made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jr034bb/

Comment: Change `.grid-half img` to `.columns img`. Then it applies to all images in that class. You can discard the `.grid-half` class, as that's just to for show.